# E1601: Cannot retrieve JMS connection info [JMSTopicService is not initialized. JMS notificationmay not be enabled]

Tags: jms, oozie, cloudera-cdh

Hi i am following below link .

http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/AG_Install.html#Notifications_Configuration

i have done all the configuration in cdh as said in the above link and restarted the oozie

Now for consumer application i have simple java main class for test purpose

code  snippet

```
OozieClient oc = new OozieClient("ooziebaseurl:11000/oozie");
JMSConnectionInfo jmsInfo = oc.getJMSConnectionInfo();
Properties jndiProperties = jmsInfo.getJNDIProperties();
Context jndiContext = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
```

while getting JMSConnectionInfo  i am having below exception

Exception in thread "main" E1601 : E1601: Cannot retrieve JMS connection info [JMSTopicService is not initialized. JMS notificationmay not be enabled]
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.handleError(OozieClient.java:508)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$JMSInfo.call(OozieClient.java:757)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$JMSInfo.call(OozieClient.java:744)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$ClientCallable.call(OozieClient.java:479)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.getJMSConnectionInfo(OozieClient.java:800)
    at com.oozie.jms.OozieJMSClient.main(OozieJMSClient.java:25)

```
few more info while debug i found that it is trying to call

http://IP:11000/oozie/v2/admin/jmsinfo 
Which says 404 
when i try to hit in the browser it says
HTTP STATUS 404 

The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

one more curious thing for me is as per link
http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/WebServicesAPI.html
```

Admin End-Point

This endpoint is for obtaining Oozie system status and configuration information.

It supports the following sub-resources: status, os-env, sys-props, configuration,  instrumentation, systems, available-timezones .

```
then why /jmsinfo is getting as a rest call ?
```

please suggest me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above is solved it was my bad. After restart the oozie with correctly updating the notification configuration it is done. Now CDH is also showing those services in the web console.